# NullPointerException when initiating the connection pool

Tags: java, db2

I have settings in the `context.xml` which contain the information for the connection of my database

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

        <Resource 
        name="jdbc/*(my username)*" 
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        removeAbandoned="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="30" 
        maxACtive="100"
        maxIdle="30" 
        maxWait="10000" 
        username= *(my username)*
        password= *(my password)*
        driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" 
        url="jdbc:db2://(my server host):50000/*(my username)*">
    </Resource>
</Context>
```

While for the Connection Pool I created a class to initiate and to connect it to the database. The error begins in the method of `getConnection()`.  The way the error is `NullPointerException` in the return of the `datasource.getConnection()`

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;


public class ConnectionPool {
    private static ConnectionPool pool = null;
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

    private ConnectionPool() {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/COMPANY");
            System.out.print(dataSource);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized ConnectionPool getInstance() {
        if (pool == null) {
            pool = new ConnectionPool();
        }
        return pool;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void freeConnection(Connection c) {
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the database connection with Eclipse's Perspective Database Development and I was able to connect and done all the queries.

In addition, it gives me this error in output

```
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2://db2.cecsresearch.org:50000/(my username)
```

Although I have the jar library files in the lib folder and in the classpath.

Comment: Is your datasource getting autowired into the connectionPool class? What I can see is that the dataSource in the class is null hence the error. The question then becomes, where is that dataSource getting set up to hold the dataSource in the XML file?

Answer (score 1):

Please download the DB2 Java driver from https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/ibm/db2/jcc/db2jcc4/10.1/db2jcc4-10.1.jar and add it to your tomcat/lib directory. Then restart Tomcat and you should be good to go !!

Answer (score 0):

The `nullpointer` is simply caused by the following problem:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2://db2.cecsresearch.org:50000/(my username)
```

Putting your database driver in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` should fix the problem.

For more info, check the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html).

> `driverClassName   (String)` The fully qualified Java class name of the
>   JDBC driver to be used. The driver has to be accessible from the same
>   classloader as tomcat-jdbc.jar

You can also check [the official jndi-datasource examples](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).

Comment: I tried to download 2 libraries jar file (commons-dbcp2, commons-pool2) and put them under WEB-INF/lib, but the error remains the same. And advice would be appreciated

Comment: As already mentioned, you should put the jars in the tomcat lib folder ($CATALINE_HOME/lib) instead of in your application lib folder (WEB-INF/lib). So if your tomcat is installed at /tmp/apache-tomcat-9.0.34, then you should put the jdbc driver jars in /tmp/apache-tomcat-9.0.34/lib.